# Laravel raw select with avg - cannot display fetched data

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have Laravel project and I want to fetch avg time. Select statement is correct but I can not display data because I get error:  `Array to string conversion`
This is my code:

```
        $limit = (int)$this->argument('distance');

        $avgTimeBetweenBlocks = DB::select('SELECT AVG(b.timediff)
            FROM
            (
            SELECT a.created_at, a.created_at_end, AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.created_at, a.created_at_end))) AS timediff
            FROM
            (
            SELECT created_at,
                (
                    SELECT max( created_at)
                    FROM block_differences bd1 
                    WHERE bd1.created_at < bd.created_at
                ) as created_at_end

            FROM block_differences bd
            limit :limit
            ) a
            WHERE a.created_at_end is not null
            GROUP BY a.created_at, a.created_at_end
                ) b', ['limit' => $limit] )->get();

        echo json_decode(json_encode($avgTimeBetweenBlocks[0]), true);
        $this->info("avgTimeBetweenBlocks {$avgTimeBetweenBlocks[0]} seconds");
```

I tried to display value in different way, but all the time I get the same result.

Comment: On which line do you get this error? And why such complicated with json encode directly inside of a decode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to `echo` an `array` here `json_decode` will convert it an array so echo will not work. use `print_r` instead of `echo`

```
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($avgTimeBetweenBlocks[0]), true));
```

Edit :-  **Array ( [AVG(b.timediff)] => 139.38775510 )**

you've to change your query. check here I give you an example below.

```
    $avgTimeBetweenBlocks = DB::select('SELECT AVG(b.timediff) as avgtimediff
                FROM
                (
                SELECT a.created_at, a.created_at_end, AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.created_at, a.created_at_end))) AS timediff
                FROM
                (
                SELECT created_at,
                    (
                        SELECT max( created_at)
                        FROM block_differences bd1 
                        WHERE bd1.created_at < bd.created_at
                    ) as created_at_end

                FROM block_differences bd
                limit :limit
                ) a
                WHERE a.created_at_end is not null
                GROUP BY a.created_at, a.created_at_end
                    ) b', ['limit' => $limit] )->get();

$response = json_decode(json_encode($avgTimeBetweenBlocks[0]), true);
echo $response['avgtimediff'];
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But now I have something like this: Array
  (
   [AVG(b.timediff)] => 139.38775510
  )
How to read this number?

Comment: Glad to help happy coding